# What is the form of the general mobius transformations that map the line $\Re(z)=2$ and the unit circle into concentric circles?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> What is the form of the general mobius transformations that map the line $\Re(z)=2$ and the circle $|z|=1$ into concentric circles centered at $a$?

I'm practicing with mobius transformations and have trouble on this question. I've tried mapping the line and the circle using $f(z) = 1/z$ and then combining the images using some sort of translation but that didn't get anywhere.

In order to find the "most general" family of such mobius transformations, I think I need to use $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{\overline a z - 1}$ which maps the unit circle onto itself, but how should this be incorporated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First $\zeta=f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ maps the line $\Re z=2$ into $|\zeta-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ and the circle $|z|=1$ into $|\zeta|=1$.
Now we  consider $\xi=\varphi (\zeta )=\frac{\zeta -c}{1-c\zeta }, \, 0<c<1.$
Of course it's aime is to map two circles $|\zeta-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ and $|\zeta|=1$ into concentric circles $|\xi |=r$ and $|\xi |=1$ centered at $0$. ($r$ is unknown at present.)

We determine $r$. By the symmetry of two circles $|\zeta-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ and $|\zeta|=1$ with respect to the real axis 
we assume
$\varphi (\frac{1}{2})=r$ and $\varphi (0)=-r$.
Thus $$
\frac{1-2c}{2-c}=r,\quad -c=-r.$$
Hence we get $c=r=2-\sqrt{3}$.

Finally take $w=\phi(\xi)=\alpha \xi +a$ or $w=\phi(\xi)=\frac{\alpha }{\xi }+a$, where $\alpha $ is a non-zero arbitrary complex number. The choice of $\alpha $ is arbitrary and it guarantees the generality of mobius transformations we consider.

Thus the form of the general mobius transformations that map the line $\Re(z)=2$ 
 and the circle $|z|=1$  into concentric circles centered at $a$ is
$$
w=(\phi\circ\varphi\circ f)(z)=\alpha\cdot \frac{1-(2-\sqrt{3})z}{z-(2-\sqrt{3})}+a
$$
and $$
w=\alpha\cdot \frac{z-(2-\sqrt{3})}{1-(2-\sqrt{3})z}+a,
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}, \, \alpha \ne 0.$

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain your symmetry argument for finding $r$? Why should $\varphi(1/2)=r$ and $\varphi(0)=-r$?

Comment: Also, how did you come up with the map $\varphi(\zeta)$? It seems to come out of nowhere for me.

Comment: We use several variables $z,\, \zeta,\, \xi,...$, since we consider $\zeta=f(z)=\frac{1}{z},\, \xi=\varphi (\zeta)=\frac{\zeta-c}{1-c\zeta},\, w=\phi(\xi) $ and those composition $\phi\circ \varphi \circ f$.

Comment: how came up with: ---
We want to find $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z} $ (which maps the unit circle onto itself) such that it  maps the circle $|z-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ onto $|z|=r$. We may specify $f(1)=1$ (if $f(1)=e^{i\theta }$, then consider $e^{-i\theta }f(z)$). 
Then $\frac{1-a}{1-\bar{a}}=1$ and we see $a$ is real. Thus we consider $\varphi (\zeta)=\frac{\zeta-c}{1-c\zeta}$.

Comment: symmetry argument: ---   
$\varphi (\frac{1}{2})$ is a point on $|\xi|=r.$  $\varphi (\frac{1}{2})$ is real, since $\varphi (x)$ is real for real $x$. Thus $\varphi (\frac{1}{2})=r$ or $-r.$
But $\varphi (\frac{1}{2})=-r$ is impossible since $\varphi ([\frac{1}{2},\, 1])$ is a line segment joining $\varphi (\frac{1}{2})$ and $\varphi (1)=1$.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 Isn't the equation of the circle after the first transformation $\lvert \zeta - \frac{1}{4} \rvert = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Sorry,typo. Thanks. It will be fixed.